# Submitting a batch of keys to a database via PHP and a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a batch of keys, then submitting them to a database that has a column called 'keycode' like this:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydatabase");

     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          exit;
     }

$keycount=0 ;

while ($keycount < 10) {

        $generatedkey = (bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6)));

        echo $generatedkey . "<br>";

        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (keycode) VALUES ('$generatedkey')");

        sleep(0.5);

        $keycount++;

        }

echo "Done. Added " . $keycount . " new keys.";

mysqli_close($con);
```

While the script itself prints all ten keys, only the first generated one shows up in the database 'keycode' column. How can I have it submit all ten of them, and what kind of delay between each submitted key (if any) is recommended here?

Comment: Strange if they're being output to the screen but not inserted into the DB... You could always try constructing a single insert query with ten lots of values then only running one query... And I don't think a delay is necessary here either to be honest.

Comment: I agree with @scrowler, better make 1 insert out the while `INSERT INTO mydatabase (keycode) VALUES ('generatedkey1'),('generatedkey1'),('generatedkey2'),('generatedkey3'),('generatedkey4'),('generatedkey5'),('generatedkey6'),('generatedkey7'),('generatedkey8'),('generatedkey10')` and generated the values inside the while

Comment: Thankyou to you and @scrowler! I retroactively tested both methods after fixing my index issue (see below), and they work fine as well. Probably a much cleaner solution to add it all in one go too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this works fine:

```
$keycount=0 ;

while ($keycount < 10) {

        $generatedkey = null;

        $generatedkey = (bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6)));

        echo $generatedkey . "<br>";

        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (keycode) VALUES ('$generatedkey')") or die(mysqli_error($connect));

        //sleep(0.5);

        $keycount++;

        }

echo "Done. Added " . $keycount . " new keys.";

mysqli_close($connect);
```

- Make sure the keycode field is varchar.

Comment: It turns out my issue was not setting an index column properly in the database. The `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` part made that super obvious! Added an auto-incrementing index column, and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

actually your last keys is stored...!, so try to store in array, and than by index of array store to DB.

```
while ($keycount < 10) {

        $generatedkey[$keycount] = (bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6)));

        echo $generatedkey[$keycount] . "<br>";

        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (keycode) 
        VALUES ('$generatedkey[$keycount]')");

        sleep(0.5);

        $keycount++;

        }
```